# Code::Blocks appearance problems

Tags: kubuntu, themes, gtk, code-blocks

I am using Code::Blocks on Kubuntu with the system theme set to Breeze-dark. When I run code blocks, the color scheme makes it look very bad.

[image: codeblocks ugly dark mode]

I am trying to force light mode for just Code::Blocks and no other apps. I would like all other apps to remain in dark mode. Does anyone know how I can make this work?
I already tried `GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Breeze/gtk-2.0/gtkrc codeblocks` and `GTK_THEME=Breeze codeblocks`.

Comment: you can probably change the colorscheme inside the program itself

Comment: There seems to be a (rather inconvenient) way of changing some of the colors, but it would still look pretty bad, because there are many things I still can't change without just setting my entire system to light theme. Is there a way that would allow me to just use the Breeze theme for codeblocks and just codeblocks?